# Selenium Webdriver 2.x & SharePoint 2010 IFrames

Tags: iframe, sharepoint-2010, selenium, webdriver

The "Add new item " link on any list in Sharepoint2010 shows up a window/frame. I want to be able to find textfields, write into them and perform other operations in the window/frame. Currently i am unsuccessful with the following methods:

BrowserInstance.SwitchTo().Frame(index) --- Exausted all indexes.
BrowserInstance.SwitchTo().Window() ---

The HTML looks something like:

```
<Div  class=some class>
<Iframe frameborder=0 ..........>
</iframe></div>
```

Selenium Webdriver (c#) identifies the div (class= some class) but not the Iframe which unfortunately holds all the fields and buttons.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to do this using selenium. So i used watin code within Selenium Test. It may not be a very good idea but Watin seems to be identifying the SharePoint 2010 iframes pretty pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

```
IWebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(1);
```

works for me.

Are you using WebDriverWait after this method? You have to wait until modal dialog loads:

```
webDriverWait.Until(drv => _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(1));

// Locate 'Name' field.
webElement = webDriverWait.Until(drv => _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//textarea[@title='Name']")));
```